# delete uploaded images inside container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i would like to delete only the images i select inside container i cant find a way to delete certain images i select when they are inside container. all i can find was to to delete all the images at the same time. this is  a web page with the working code  https://torcdesign.com/mars/ and this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kk5r1p2b/19/ the fiddle contains the same exact code as my web page but for some reason the code stopped working

```html
<div id="firstshirt" class="container" style="float:left;">
<center><div id="wrapper"><div id="boxes" class="container5" style="float:center;">
 <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
   <div class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        
      
      
</div></div>
<div class="samson">
<img id="output1" class="out-put-img1" style="position: absolute;top: 108px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"></div>
<div class="dragbal1">
 <img id="output2" class="out-put-img2" style="position: absolute;top: 108px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"></div>
<div class="chinass2">
 <img id="output4" class="out-put-img4" style="position: absolute;top: 108px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"></div></span></a><div id="fotos" class="bananas"><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div></div></div></center><br><br><br><br></div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle has a ton of code that doesn't seem to pertain to your problem. Can you whittle it down to the code that is relevant to your issue please? It's unclear what code deletes stuff, which I'm assuming is the code you're having issues with?

Comment: i dont have a code that deletes . and all the code that i have is for a good reason. in the past i "watered down" my code when i got an answer and tried to put into my regular code it didn't seem to work as it did with the "watered down" code. i have reason to believe that the shirt image has something to do with it and the reason why the upload is not working on my fiddle is because of  </script> tag i cant use that in fiddle,.